Lexical Editor and Next JS
I am using lexical in next js.
Using npm run dev, evverything works.
on npm run build, I get the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at oo (6506-58498e6309b8c34d.js:1:128656)
at Po.setRootElement (6506-58498e6309b8c34d.js:1:150077)
...

Below is my Lexical file.
import { $getRoot } from "lexical";
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";
import { LexicalComposer } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposer";
import { ContentEditable } from "@lexical/react/LexicalContentEditable";
import MyLexicalTheme from "../lexical-theme";
import ToolbarPlugin from "./ToobarPlugin";
import { RichTextPlugin } from "@lexical/react/LexicalRichTextPlugin";
import { $generateHtmlFromNodes } from "@lexical/html";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const theme = MyLexicalTheme;


function onError(error) {

  throw error;
}

function LexicalEditorWrapper({
  setMyCommentText,
  setEditorAndRootValuesInParent,
}) {
  const initialConfig = {
    namespace: "MyEditor",
    theme,
    onError,
  };
  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
      <div className="editor-container">
        <div className="editor-inner">
          <RichTextPlugin
            contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
            placeholder={
              <div className="editor-placeholder">Enter some text...</div>
            }
          />
   
        </div>
      </div>
    </LexicalComposer>
  );
}

export default LexicalEditorWrapper;

Please any idea how I can resolve this? Internet searches does not reveal much. I am using lexical version ^0.16.0

What NextJS version are you using ?

@Beast80K "^12.1.0"

I encountered the same issue. After testing, I found that the problem only occurred after the code was minified and obfuscated. So, I tried to determine whether it was an issue with the compression tool. When I changed the JS minifier to esbuild and set the target to ['chrome80', 'es2020'], the problem was resolved. You might want to give it a try.

It saves me a ton of time. Thank you so much!

Adding swcMinify: true to next.config.js worked out for me
